# Issue choosing between plural or singular of a word

Tags: python

The problem is that when I reach "2 bottles of beer/Take one down/Pass it around" the next verse is "1 bottles of beer on the wall" instead of "1 bottle".

```
def bottles(count):
    for i in reversed(range(count+True)):
        plural = 's' if i-True else ''
        print("{} bottle{} of beer on the wall.\n".format(i, plural))
        print("{} bottle{} of beer.\n".format(i, plural))
        if not i-True: break
        print("Take one down, pass it around.\n")
        print("{} bottle{} of beer on the wall.\n".format(i - 1, plural))

if __name__ == '__main__':       
    bottles(99)
```

Comment: `if i-True`...?!

Comment: Why do you write `if i - True`. That's **ugly**! It may work - but why no `if i > 1` or any other alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You need `i > 1` instead as the condition as `i - 1` is true when `i == 0` as `bool(-1)` is `True`.

Comment: I need i > 1 instead of what? I replaced i-True with i > 1 and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the line:

> `print("{} bottle{} of beer on the wall.\n".format(i - 1, plural))`

When *i=2*, you get:

> "1 bottles of beer on the wall."

You would have to update plural before this line!

Comment: Can you be more explicit? On how should I update plural.